# I want to generate & compile Visual Studio projet with CMake I need to exclude unit testing files from the build. Is there a way to dothis?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

My project contain unit testing file I want to excludes from the compilation process. I want to modify the .vcxproj Visual Studio file with CMake. What could be the possible solutions of my issue ?

```
set_source_files_properties(BankTestCase_1.h PROPERTIES VS_DEPLOYEMENT_CONTENT 0)

set_source_files_properties(BankTestCase_1.h PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_BUILD 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't modify a `.vcxproj` file. CMake generates one. Each time you invoke cmake, a new project file is generated. You have to generate it correctly.

---

CMake has already a function defined just to add tests. It's called [`add_test`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html)

It work by specifying a name then a command or executable target:

```
add_executable(my_test_exe testsrc1.cpp testsrc2.cpp)
add_test(NAME MyTest COMMAND my_test_exe)
```

If you also want to not compile the test files in your main project, simply don't add them to your main target:

```
add_executable(main_project
    src1.cpp
    src2.cpp
    src3.cpp
    src4.cpp
    # srctest1.cpp # not added
    # srctest2.cpp # not added too.
)
```

Also, I notice that you want to remove header files from compilation. Header files are not supposed to be compiled at all. You should not add them to your target.

---

If you used globs to add all source files, then you can always remove it from the glob list:

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM globbed_files file/to/be_excluded.cpp)
```